Little o multiplication rule backwards
Is $c(x) \in o(a(x)b(x)) \Rightarrow c(x) \in o(a(x))o(b(x))$ for $x\to x_0$ generally valid?

Can we re-state it like this?  If $\lim \frac{c(x)}{a(x)b(x)}=0$, then there exist $c_1(x), c_2(x)$ so that $c(x) = c_1(x)c_2(x)$ and $\lim\frac{c_1(x)}{a(x)}=0$ and $\lim\frac{c_2(x)}{b(x)}=0$ ...?  In this forum you should show your own attempt to avoid closure.

Yes! It's quite hard to have an own attempt as the task is to find such functions.

I'll assume $a,b,c$ are strictly positive for simplicity.
Let
\begin{align*}
d(x) &= \frac{c(x)}{a(x)b(x)} \\
c_1(x) &= a(x)\sqrt{d(x)} \\
c_2(x) &= b(x)\sqrt{d(x)}
\end{align*}
Then we have $c_1c_2 = c$ and $c_1 \in o(a)$ and $c_2 \in o(b)$ by continuity of $\sqrt{x}$ as $x \to 0^+$.
